# Failed to connect , connection refused

Tags: docker, curl, networking, port

I am setting up a blockchain network . One of my node is running on port 11628 of my machine, and another node is running inside a docker container on port 11625. I want to access the node running on my machine from inside the docker container. When I do

```
>curl localhost:11628
```

In machine It works fine. I understand that I cannot execute this command inside container as localhost would mean to itself.
When I do execute

```
route
```

inside docker container, it gives output

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         172.17.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
```

So I also tried `curl 172.17.0.1:11628` it also gives

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.1 port 11628: Connection refused
```

What should I do now ?
Is there any problem with exposing the port ?
I started container by command

```
docker run -it --name container_name image
```

Comment: What host is your blockchain server running on? If it's listening on `localhost` / `127.0.0.1` then that makes sense, ensure that it's listening on `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: How do I ensure it ?  My simple query is that what is the equivalent address which should I send request to in docker  in order to get the same effect as of localhost:11628 in the machine

Comment: What is your blockchain server on the host? What command do you use to run it?